# Cannot get / undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, undefined

I was trying to add transitions to my website, all a> tags work perfectly WITH THE TRANSITIONS but when I add this js SOMETIMES telling me this error:
`Cannot GET /pages/undefined`

Then when I try to open the same link in the same html, works. I have already made sure that all the links are matched perfectly the, thing is that js don't find the link sometimes as says that is undefined. Here is all the code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    
      <div class="transition transition-1 active"></div>
    
        <div class="header">
            <nav>
              <a href="../index.html">
                <span class="main-text">Phibik</span>
              </a>
              </button>
              <div class="main-nav">
                <ul id="menu">
                  <li>
                    <a href="inicio.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Inicio</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="games.html"><i class="fas fa-gamepad"></i>Games</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="edits.html"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i>Edits</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="random.html"><i class="fas fa-random"></i>Random</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="about.html"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>About</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <div id="hamburger" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                  <div class="bar1"></div>
                  <div class="bar2"></div>
                  <div class="bar3"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.transition-1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #202020;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}

.transition-1.active {
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

JS:

```
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}

const hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger");
const navUL = document.getElementById("menu");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navUL.classList.toggle("show");
});

window.onload = () => {
  const transition_el = document.querySelector(".transition");
  const anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a");

  setTimeout(() => {
    transition_el.classList.remove("active");
  }, 500);

  for (let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    const anchor = anchors[i];

    anchor.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let target = e.target.href;

      transition_el.classList.add("active");

      setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.href = target;
      }, 500);
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let target = e.target.href;` gives you the `href` of the element that was clicked on.

> ```
> <a href="random.html"><i class="fas fa-random"></i>Random</a>
> ```

If someone clicks on your italic content, inside your link, then it isn't going to have an `href` property so you get `undefined`.

---

[`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) will give you the element to which the event handler is bound.